# how to write an IF formula in excel or spreadsheets if you want to check for links

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I was wondering if it was possible to write an IF formula in excel or sheets that would check if the cell contained a link. Currently there are rows of data that strings and some data that have web addresses.

Is it possible to write if formula for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use just off-the-shelf available Excel functions you could us "=Find()" or "=Search()" to test if a cell had any of the common elements of a web address, e.g. "www." or ".com" etc. You might have to nest a few "=IFERROR()" statements or use "=IFERROR(OR(),,)" to cover the possibilities. 
You would want to use "=IFERROR()" to trap out errors for the cells that don't have any common web address elements.
So, it might look like "=IFERROR(FIND("www",A1)>0,0)" this would return a "TRUE" if it found "www" and a "0" if it didn't and you could nest that in another "=IF()" statement.
It's not bullet proof but it might be sufficient.
I don't know of an Excel function that specifically tests for a hyperlink in a cell.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about using a formula, but you can do this easily with VBA if you feel so inclined:

```
If Range("A1").Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
  MsgBox "A hyperlink"
Else
  MsgBox "NOT a hyperlink"
End If
```

The above checks if cell `A1` contains a hyperlink or not. It's simplistic, but hopefully you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VBA you could write your own user defined function which could then be used in an if statement.

```
Function ishyperlink(r As Range) As Boolean

If r.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
    ishyperlink = True
Else
    ishyperlink = False
End If

End Function
```

in the cell `=if(ishyperlink(A1),"hyper","no hyper")`